# Mobile Device Popup in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I have Android and IOs apps for my website and for promotion of my apps I added banners in website but I want some thing different.

When someone visits my website a pop-up appears and ask them to download app or they may continue without downloading same as if you visit Ask.fm website from mobile phone.

Any idea,tutorial or help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple popup using jquery.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="popblock" class="blockpopup">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="blockpopup_close"><img src="popup_close.png"></a>
you details or link
</div>
</div>

<script>
function openpopup(){
jQuery("body").append("<div class='blockpopup_closeoverlay'></div>").fadeIn(400);
jQuery(".blockpopup").slideUp(500).fadeIn(500);
}jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){ openpopup();}, 1000);    

        jQuery(".blockpopup_close, .blockpopup_closeoverlay").live("click", function() {
        jQuery(".blockpopup_closeoverlay").delay(500).fadeOut(400);
        jQuery(".blockpopup").slideDown(500).fadeOut(500);
});
})
</script>
```